# c# holding keys and shift at the same time

Tags: c#

I'm trying to increase the piece speed by holding A (or D) and Shilf at the same time like below

```
private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.A:
            if (position.X > 5)
                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                    position.X-=6;
                else
                    position.X-=3;
            break;

        case Keys.D:
            if (position.X < 500)
                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
                    position.X-=6;
                else
                    position.X-=3;  
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

It worked, but only if I press Shift first then A (or D), if I hold A and then Shift, it stop. Can anyone help? I'm new to this.

Comment: Don't rely on the keyboard repeat feature.  Google "c# windows forms game loop" to get ahead.